# How to transfer data from one activity to another?

Tags: android

I am trying to transfer data from one page to another but some problem is coming below is the code. I am trying to transfer value of variable using bundle from first activity to second but something is wrong please tell me whats going wrong.

below is first activity:-

```
package route.planning;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class login extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Context mCtx;
    final static int START =0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mCtx = this;


        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        //  @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String fromLat = new String();
            String fromLong = new String();
            String toLat = new String();
            String toLong = new String();

            fromLat=String.valueOf(R.id.FromLatitude);
            fromLong=String.valueOf(R.id.FromLongitude);
            toLat=String.valueOf(R.id.ToLatitude);
            toLong=String.valueOf(R.id.ToLongitude);


            Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MapRouteActivity.class);

            /*Sending some arguments*/ 
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

              bundle.putString("fromLat",fromLat );
              bundle.putString("fromLong",fromLong );
              bundle.putString("toLat",toLat );
              bundle.putString("toLong",toLong );


              intent.putExtras(bundle);

            /*Start Activity*/
            mCtx.startActivity(intent);

            /*Start ActivityForResult*/
            ((Activity)mCtx).startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == START)
        {

            Toast.makeText(mCtx, Integer.toString(resultCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Below is part of second activity where i am trying to get value from above

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.ci.geo.route.Road;
import org.ci.geo.route.RoadProvider;

import route.planning.R;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class MapRouteActivity extends MapActivity {

        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        MapView mapView;
        private Road mRoad;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.routeplanning);
                mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
                mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

                Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
                final String fLat=extras.getString("fromLat");
                final String fLong=extras.getString("fromLong");
                final String tLat=extras.getString("toLat");
                final String tLong=extras.getString("toLong");



                new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            double fromLat=Double.parseDouble(fLat);
                            double fromLon=Double.parseDouble(fLong);
                            double toLat=Double.parseDouble(tLat);
                            double toLon=Double.parseDouble(tLong);
                              //double fromLat = 28.6353, fromLon = 77.2250, toLat = 30.7313, toLon = 76.7754;
                                /***url contains the path to fetch the kml file from the internet*/
                                String url = RoadProvider
                                                .getUrl(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon);
                                InputStream is = getConnection(url);
                                mRoad = RoadProvider.getRoute(is);
                                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        }
                }.start();
        }
```

Comment: What is wrong?? You do not say what the problem is. This code looks fine to me at a quick glance.

Comment: @Harry: That is how he has done, but he says it's not working. So it may be something else that is wrong.

Comment: somehow in the thread the values are not going.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        fromLat=String.valueOf(R.id.FromLatitude);
        fromLong=String.valueOf(R.id.FromLongitude);
        toLat=String.valueOf(R.id.ToLatitude);
        toLong=String.valueOf(R.id.ToLongitude);
```

Here is the problem. You don't read any actual data from the activity, but get the string represantation of identifiers of controls.

You need to obtain the user inputs if R.id.FromLatitude and so on are identifiers of EditText:

```
fromLat = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.FromLatitude)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: i will make the changes and get back to you.

Comment: hi, now the app is not going to the second activity after making the above changes. its force closing the app after i am pressing the button

Comment: ask another question and don't forget about the stacktrace.

Comment: hi i have asked a new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873185/how-to-transfer-input-taken-at-one-activity-to-another-avtivity   with the stack trace please help me

Answer (score 1):

You won't get the values from the following code which you have used:

```
    fromLat=String.valueOf(R.id.FromLatitude);
    fromLong=String.valueOf(R.id.FromLongitude);
    toLat=String.valueOf(R.id.ToLatitude);
    toLong=String.valueOf(R.id.ToLongitude);
```

This way, you're accessing the IDs of these views, which will be in int.
You have to get the instance of the views (`EditText`, here) then have to extract their value.

Go with @Vladimir's solution, its perfect.

Comment: Hi, i tried with Vladimir's solution but its not working for me.before it was starting the second activity now its force closing the application after clicking the button. please help me

Comment: Are you familiar with the logcat tool in eclipse? check messages in it when the Force Close happens, and post here. secondly, post your new code here, either put it on gist.github.com (preferred) or simply edit the question. Then I can be of much more help.

Comment: hi i have asked a new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873185/how-to-transfer-input-taken-at-one-activity-to-another-avtivity   with the stack trace please help me

Answer (score 1):

Remove final keyword from Second activity:

```
final String fLat=extras.getString("fromLat");
final String fLong=extras.getString("fromLong");
final String tLat=extras.getString("toLat");
final String tLong=extras.getString("toLong");
```

to

```
String fLat=extras.getString("fromLat");
String fLong=extras.getString("fromLong");
String tLat=extras.getString("toLat");
String tLong=extras.getString("toLong");
```