# getting data from one activity to another

Tags: android

i have two activities that is friends and details, the friends activity is a list view with the list data populated from a database i already created, when a list item is clicked, the details activity should be launched and the list item data carried to the details activity and put into the edit text box in the details class

```
package com.rich.myfinal;

public class FriendsActivity extends Activity {

     private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
     private PersonDataHelper databaseHelper;
     private ListView listView;

     private static final String TAG = FriendsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
     /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);

        databaseHelper = new PersonDataHelper(this);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
         });

         // Database query can be a time consuming task ..
         // so its safe to call database query in another thread
         // Handler, will handle this stuff for you <img src="http://s0.wp.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif?m=1129645325g" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley">

         new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(FriendsActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData());
                 listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
             }
         });
     }
}
```

The details activity is below

```
package com.rich.myfinal;

public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {
    EditText details;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        details = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.details);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is problem you facing?

Comment: i need help with the code to copy the data to the details activity

Comment: You could have searched for.  This question comes up at least once per day.  Here's one example of the hundreds on here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860811/how-to-transfer-data-from-one-activity-to-another?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways, one is using Bundle and the another one throught Intent.

**Using Bundle,**

To Send:

```
Intent passIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Key", "Value");
passIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(passIntent);
```

To Receive:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String recText = bundle.getString("Key");
```

**Using Through Intent:**

To Send:

```
Intent passIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
passIntent.putExtras("Key", "Value");
startActivity(passIntent);
```

To Receive:

```
String recText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key");
```

For your Code, in your FirstActivity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
                    Intent passIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    passIntent.putExtras("Key", position);
                    startActivity(passIntent);
                }
            });



In SecondActivity,


details.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass values you want from `FriendsActivity` to `DetailsActivity` activity with `Intent` like below. Pass values from FriendsActivity when you start another activity by calling `startActivity()`

```
intent.putExtra("pos", v.getId()) ;
intent.putExtra("TranObject",(Serializable) data.get(v.getId()).getTranse()) ;
```

And then receive values in `DetailsActivity` as below in `onCreate()`

```
    try {
        pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");
        blog =(clsTranscation) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("TranObject");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use like that

```
 @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
                      String value = listView .getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
                       i.putExtra("data", value);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

use in detail Activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String value= bundle.getString("data");
details = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.details);
details.setText(value)
```

Comment: sunil, in my edit text box, am getting "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@45fcf1100" what does it mean?

Comment: what is this? In your detail part activity nothing related this code.So it should not comes, Are you sure it comes in detail Activity part?

Answer (score 0):

just call `String value=YourList.get(position);`
And pass this in Intent using `intent.putExtra("Key","Value");`

And get this value using `Bundle bundle=getIntent.getExtra();` ,

```
String value=bundle.getExtra("Key");
```